# Does the Nikon D7000 video overheat like the D90?

Tags: nikon, nikon-d7000

I currently have a D90 and I'm shooting more and more video so I was considering going to the D7000.

My question is, does the D7000 overheat after 5 consecutive 5min shooting and automatically shut down or is this something of the past?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nikon D7000 can shoot 20 minutes video continuously. It has also full time autofocus.
[Here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QZPNwIMMFik) at the end of video you can see the quality and how well fulltime autofocus works.

I have shot 2-3 hours of video in a row without any overheating problems.

Comment: Thanks @Aram Sahradyan , but do you know if I shoot 2 20min in row, will it overheat?

Comment: No, it will not. I made 2-3 hours of video in a row and it was ok

Answer (score 4):

I have owned a D7000 for a year and I have shot video for hours with just small breaks in between.  I have never had an overheating problem.

Comment: Same here. It is obviously a little warm, but nothing like overheating. Even in outdoor use in fairly warm weather.